# Removing empty hashes in Rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

In rabl I'm trying to have a child whose elements are conditional, but in the cases where to condition evaluates false it's still rendering elements which have no attributes.

Here's my .rabl:

```
child(:products) do
  attribute :id, :if => lambda{ |p| p.store_id == @store.id }
end
```

Hoping for .json that looks something like this:

```
"products":[{"id":2}]
```

But it's rendering empty values as well:

```
"products":[{}, {"id":2}, {}]
```

Is there a way I can make it so that empty elements are ignored entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are expecting a `products` method on an instance variable:

```
child(@catalogue.products.select{|p| p.store_id == @store.id} => :products ) do
  attribute :id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm. U can do this way.

```
[{},{a: "b"},{}].reject {|h| h.blank?}
```

Comment: I can't actually manipulate `"products":[{}, {"id":2}, {}]` that's just the JSON that rabl is rendering.

Comment: Hmmm. I haven't tried rabl. However U can try doing this. It's a quess. Just try putting `end.reject {|h| h.blank?}` after the "do end".Mostly It should do the Trick.